# With Twilio, is it possible to receive user input during a conference call?

Tags: twilio

The [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) mentions that you can collect user keypad input while they are listening to a message:

> You can nest the following verbs within Gather: Say, Play, Pause. But you can't nest Gather within any other verbs.

The Conference tag cannot be nested within the Gather tag, so is there another way to collect user digits once they are connected to a conference room using the Conference tag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't a way to `<Gather>` while in a conference call, but there is a work around.  You can leverage the `<Dial>` verbs hangupOnStar attribute.

```
<Response>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true">
        <Conference>example</Conference>
    </Dial>
    <Gather action="/redirectIntoConference?name=example" numDigits="1"></Gather>
</Response>
```

When the user presses the `*` key, Twilio will disconnect them fro mthe conference call and immediately start to listen for them to press tones.  When the Gather completes you would just redirect them back into the conference call.

This enables you to do things like the standard `*6` key combination to mute.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I love it.  Very powerful combination!

Comment: Just implemented it.  Works great.

Comment: Is this still true, i.e., "You can't GATHER during a conference"??

Comment: Yes, its still true.

Comment: Hey Devin can you help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157444/real-time-transcription-twilio-agent-conference) please!

Comment: Hey Devin, How would this look on a Ruby controller with REST please? I already have the dial = Twillio::twiml:dial.new and dial.conference(xxxxxx...) response. append(dial), render xml: response.to_s

Comment: @philnash ^^^  you can probably answer this faster than I can.

Comment: This is a very clever solution, great idea!

Comment: @DevinRader, is this possible with the create participant functions?  I don't see the hangupOnStar as an option when adding a participant this way.  https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only