# How to detect Touch-tones (DTMF) in a Twilio video room

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-video

After following [this document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/adding-programmable-voice-participants-video-rooms) I can successfully add PSTN callers to a video room (Small Room type). What I haven't been able to do is to detect DTMF tones from the person calling in.

I tried two different approaches, both have failed

1) The one that I used before with a different provider and worked, but not with Twilio, was to have one of the other users in the room (not the PSTN caller but a javascript client) detect the DTMF client-side. This doesn't work with twilio because it sounds to me like twilio is manipulating the audio stream to remove the DTMFs before they reach the other users in the room (when the PSTN caller presses a number, you only hear a short "click" on the other side)

2) Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28621852/1086540), I tried to reply with a TWIML

```
<Response>
  <Connect>
    <Room>my-room</Room>
  </Connect>
  <Gather input="dtmf">
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

This would not be ideal since it wouldn't detect the DTMF while in the room; you would have to leave the room, but I tried it anyway to see if I could come up with a way to terminate the call to move on to the `gather` verb like in the linked answer. It looks like the call doesn't move to the gather part after the room ends (i tried completing the room and the PSTN call immediately ends)

Are there any other approaches that anyone has used for this? The simplest to me would be a way to tell twilio not to remove the DTMFs from the audio stream so my solution #1 would work, but I'm open to other ideas maybe leveraging twilio's `gather`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It doesn't look like it's currently directly possible to detect DTMF tones in a phone call that has been connected to a video room.

One possibility is to use [the new Media Stream capability](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream) to direct the live audio to your own server to detect the tones.

I have asked the team to see if there are other options though.

Comment: Thank you @philnash. Can you confirm that the DTMFs are being removed from the audio stream that the other participants get in the room? would it be possible to deactivate this feature? on quick tests, it looks like this is not the case in a regular voice call, why remove them in a video room but not in a regular voice call? could i create somewhere a feature request to expose this configuration in the room creation api?

Comment: also, if i use your suggestion of the media stream to direct the audio to a server, how do you suggest that I notify the participants in the room about detected DTMFs? i don't see anything in the Room API that would let me pass that info to the room

Comment: I am checking this with the team internally to see what is going on.

Comment: after two years, is this now possible or are DTMF tones still removed from PSTN calls connected to video rooms? thank you for any pointers

Comment: According to the Voice team, the SDP negotiation we make with the carrier should mean that DTMF tones are actually sent out-of-band, so down a different channel than the regular voice audio. Thus the DTMF tones are inaudible on that voice audio stream. So, the tones are not removed from the call, just sent in a different manner.

Comment: Oh that's very interesting. So if i understand correctly, a twilio-video js client joins a room, my backend does a pstn call and joins it to the room and now the twilio-video js client will receive the DTMFs of the pstn user via the same twilio video SDK?? any idea what js calls should i do to get a hold of that "different channel" where the dtmfs go?

Comment: No, the DTMF that is sent out-of-band is dropped by Twilio outside of the context of a `<Gather>` or a `<Dial>` (where you can hang up with `*`). There is no access to this out-of-band channel from the Voice API or the Video SDK.

Comment: ah! i get it :( thank you for your help phil

Comment: Sorry it’s not what you’d hoped for.