# Is it possible to pass DTMF tones to Twilio Video room participant?

Tags: twilio, dtmf, twilio-video

We have a video room participant which we need pass DTMF to. We are adding him to video room as described here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/adding-programmable-voice-participants-video-rooms. Then we use custom dtmf tone javascript generator and add it's track to room audio tracks. It seems to be working, since we are able to hear tones as other room participants. But that participant can't recognize tones.
Seems like dtmf isn't working according to this [How to detect Touch-tones (DTMF) in a Twilio video room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666508/how-to-detect-touch-tones-dtmf-in-a-twilio-video-room), but I'm curious haven't this beed fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who has faced with same issue - Twilio support has confirmed it is still impossible for now. They have plans to implement, but dates are unknown.